# Pandas store filenames in list and read all the files into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, filelist

Hi I am trying to search for specified filenames using glob and re. Once the match is found i am storing the list of matched files into a text file. What i need is that i want to fetch all these matched file names into a list so that i can store them into a single dataframe .

```
import re
import sys
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import logging

with open('files_matched.txt', 'w') as f_matched, open('files_not_matched.txt','w') as f_notmatched:
    try:
        for file in glob.glob('*.csv'):
                r = re.search(r'abc_sales(20[0-9][0-9])-([1-9]|1[0-2]|0[0-9])-([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]|0[0-9])-[0-9]{2}_[a-z0-9]{3,5}.csv', file)
                if r:
                    filename=[file] # unable to store list of files 
                    match=f'File matched:{file}'
                    f_matched.write(match+'\n')
                else:
                    not_match=f'File not matched:{file}'
                    f_notmatched.write(not_match + '\n')
    except Exception as e:
        pass

df=[pd.read_csv(f,encoding='ISO-8859-1',error_bad_lines=False,engine='python') for f in filename]

for df_new, f in zip(df,filename):
      df_new['f'] = f
combined_df = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=False)
combined_df.head()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new list of files by `append` and then create new column by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
filenames = []
with open('files_matched.txt', 'w') as f_matched, open('files_not_matched.txt','w') as f_notmatched:
    try:
        for file in glob.glob('*.csv'):
                r = re.search(r'abc_sales(20[0-9][0-9])-([1-9]|1[0-2]|0[0-9])-([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]|0[0-9])-[0-9]{2}_[a-z0-9]{3,5}.csv', file)
                if r:
                    filenames.append(file) # add filename to list 
                    match=f'File matched:{file}'
                    f_matched.write(match+'\n')
                else:
                    not_match=f'File not matched:{file}'
                    f_notmatched.write(not_match + '\n')
    except Exception as e:
        pass

#add new column by assign
df=[pd.read_csv(f,
                encoding='ISO-8859-1',
                error_bad_lines=False,
                engine='python').assign(f = f) 
    for f in filenames]

combined_df = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=False)
```

Comment: @AnkitKumarSharma - You are welcome. Also if need remove extension for column use `import os`  and `.assign(f=os.path.basename(f))` instead `assign(f = f)`